# SAS DATA step / INPUT statement: reading column-based raw data AND multiple observations from single line?

Tags: sas

I’m working with some raw data that has fixed column widths, but has all its records written into a single line (blame the data vendor, not me :-) ).  I know how to use
fixed column widths in the `INPUT` statement, and how to use `@@` to read more than one observation per line, but I am having trouble when I try to do both.

As an example, here’s some code where the data has fixed column widths, but there is one line per record.  This code works fine:

```
DATA test_1;
    INPUT alpha $ 1-5   beta $ 6-10   gamma 11-15 ;

    DATALINES;
a    f    1
ab   fg   12
abc  fgh  123
abcd fghi 1234
abcdefghij12345
    ;
RUN;
```

Now here’s the code for what I’m really trying to do – all the data is in one line, and I try to use the `@@` notation:

```
DATA test_2;
    INPUT alpha $ 1-5    beta $ 6-10    gamma 11-15 @@;

    DATALINES;
a    f    1    ab   fg   12   abc  fgh  123  abcd fghi 1234 abcdefghij12345
    ;
RUN;
```

This fails because it just keeps reading the beginning 15 characters, holding that record, and re-reading from the start. Based on my understanding of the semantics of the `@@` notation, I can definitely understand why this would be happening.

Is there any way I can accomplish reading fixed column data from a single line; that is, make `test_2` have the same content as `test_1`?  Perhaps through some combination of symbols in the `INPUT` statement, or maybe resorting to another method (with file I/O functions, `PROC IMPORT`, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried specifying variable lengths using informats?

For example:

```
DATA test_2;
    INPUT alpha  $5.    beta $5.    gamma 5.0 @@;

    DATALINES;
a    f    1    ab   fg   12   abc  fgh  123  abcd fghi 1234 abcdefghij12345
;
RUN;
```

From the SAS documentation:

> Formatted input causes the pointer to move like that of column input
>   to read a variable value. The pointer moves the length that is
>   specified in the informat and stops at the next column.

Comment: Nice...not sure what I was doing differently, but just tested it and it works on the sample data

Comment: Wow, I'm so used to working with columns of varying widths and using the `:` notation that I forgot about specifying absolute widths by just dropping the `:` and specifying the width.  I'm accepting this answer right now, but I was hoping you could also tell me:  why do people say `alpha $ 1-5` when they could just say `alpha $ 5`?  Is the former notation some kind of legacy support?  Anyway, thanks for the great answer.

Comment: alpha $ 1-5 and alpha $5 do different things. The first reads from the columns 1-5 in the current input line (and this is the root cause of the original problem). The second reads the NEXT 5 characters from the current position. So one doesn't superseded another, they are complementary.